# VSCode doesn't recognize python cells - CVE instead

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, cve

I try to run a notebook with the `.ipynb` extension, and the Jupyter notebook doesn't allow me to convert the cell to Python.
When I click on the language button in the right-down corner, Python is on the list but it converts it automatically to CVE.
What does this even mean? And how I can change it to Python?

Here is what appears to me:

[image: here]

And when I click on it, I got the following:

[image: here]

Comment: What is CVE you mention?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it as following:

**Reason for the issue**

There seems to be an issue between the **Jupyter Notebook extension** and the **Dependency Analytics** extension. (See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7917, Answer from rchiodo )

**Solution**

I went to extensions ( in VS-Code ) and deactivated the **Dependeny Analytics** extension. After restarting VS-Code I was able to set python as the cell language

Comment: Thanks! it is working now!